# Read CSV file in Java and extracting certain data from the read file

Tags: java, csv, bufferedreader, getter-setter, pojo

I have read a csv file into Java using POJO class.The file has 19 column with header and I would like to extract information from one of header. How do I do that?  Would appreciate some guidance and advises from the community.

[image: The csv file looks like that]

Here are some of my codes:

I would like to access "EWR" from the Origin Variable and print out there are how many EWR from the data. I was trying to use a getter to extract the data I want but it did not work out. I got 0 when I tried to print the size.

```
public class nycflights13 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        NYC13data ABC = new NYC13data ();
        List<Flights> EWRairport = new ArrayList <> ();
        for (Flights ab : ABC.NYC13.fdata) {
            if(ab.getorigin().equals("EWR")){
                EWRairport.add(ab);
            } else {
                continue;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(EWRairport.size());
    }   
}
```

Here are my class `NYC13data` :

```
class NYC13data {
    flightdata NYC13 = new flightdata ();

    public flightdata getList (){
        return NYC13;
    }

    public NYC13data () {
        NYC13.readFileFromCSV("C:\\Users\\boonl\\Desktop\\R Assignment\\flights.csv");
    }
}
```

Here are my class `flightdata` :

```
class flightdata {
    public List<Flights> fdata;

    public List<Flights> readFileFromCSV (String fileName){
        Path pathToFile = Paths.get(fileName);

        try(BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(pathToFile,
                StandardCharsets.US_ASCII)){
            br.readLine();
            String line = br.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                String [] variable = line.split(",");

                //convert string array to list
                List<String> list = Arrays.asList(variable);
                if(list.contains("NA")) {
                    line = br.readLine();
                    continue;
                } else {
                    Flights dataset = createFlights(variable);
                    fdata.add(dataset);
                    line = br.readLine();
                }

            }
        }catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }

        return fdata;

    }

    //Did not show all the 19 variables
    private static Flights createFlights (String [] metadata) {
        int year = Integer.parseInt(metadata[1]);
        int month = Integer.parseInt(metadata[2]);
        int day = Integer.parseInt(metadata[3]);
        String flight = metadata[11]; 
        String tailnum = metadata[12];
        String origin = metadata[13];
        String dest = metadata[14]; 
        String time_hour = metadata[19];

        return new Flights(year, month, day, dep_time, sched_dep_time, dep_delay, arr_time,
                sched_arr_time, arr_delay, carrier, flight, tailnum, origin, dest, air_time,
                distance, hour, minute, time_hour);
    }

    public flightdata () {
        fdata = new ArrayList <> ();    
    }

    public void printdata () {
        for(Flights ab : fdata) {
            System.out.println(ab);
        }
    }
}
```

Here are my class `Flights` :

```
class Flights {

    private int year; private int month; private int day; private int dep_time;
    private int sched_dep_time; private int dep_delay; private int arr_time;
    private int sched_arr_time; private int arr_delay; private String carrier;
    private String flight; private String tailnum; private String origin;
    private String dest; private int air_time; private int distance;
    private int hour; private int minute; private String time_hour;

    public Flights(int year, int month, int day, int dep_time, int sched_dep_time,
            int dep_delay, int arr_time, int sched_arr_time, 
            int arr_delay, String carrier, String flight, String tailnum,
            String origin, String dest, int air_time, int distance,
            int hour, int minute, String time_hour) {
        this.year = year; this.month = month; this.day = day; this.dep_time = dep_time;
        this.sched_dep_time = sched_dep_time; this.dep_delay = dep_delay; this.arr_time = arr_time;
        this.sched_arr_time = sched_arr_time; this.arr_delay = arr_delay; this.carrier = carrier; 
        this.flight = flight; this.tailnum = tailnum; this.origin = origin; 
        this.dest = dest; this.air_time = air_time; this.distance = distance; 
        this.hour = hour; this.minute = minute; this.time_hour = time_hour; 
    }

    public int getyear() {return year;}
    public void setYear(int year) {this.year = year;}

    public int getmonth() {return month;}
    public void setMonth(int month) {this.month = month; }

    public int getday() {return day;}
    public void setDay(int day) {this.day = day; }

    public String getcarrier() {return carrier;}
    public void setcarrier(String carrier) {this.carrier = carrier;}

    public String getflight() {return flight;}
    public void setflight(String flight) {this.flight = flight; }

    public String gettailnum() {return tailnum;}
    public void settailnum(String tailnum) {this.tailnum = tailnum; }

    public String getorigin() {return origin;}
    public void setorigin(String origin) {this.origin = origin; }

    public String getdest() {return dest;}
    public void setdest(String dest) {this.dest = dest; }

    public String gettime_hour() {return time_hour;}
    public void settime_hour(String time_hour) {this.time_hour = time_hour; }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Flights [year=" + year +", month=" + month +", day=" + day +", dep_time=" + dep_time 
                + ", sched_dep_time=" + sched_dep_time +", dep_delay=" + dep_delay +", arr_time=" + 
                arr_time + ", sched_arr_time=" + sched_arr_time +", arr_delay=" + arr_delay +", 
                carrier=" + carrier + ", flight=" + flight +", tailnum=" + tailnum +", origin=" + 
                origin +", dest=" + dest ", air_time=" + air_time +", distance=" + distance +", 
                hour=" + hour +", minute=" + minute +", time_hour=" + time_hour +"]";
    }
}
```

Would really appreciate if anyone here could guide me what is wrong with my code. Thanks a million.

Comment: That code doesn't even compile. Try again!! See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Could you check that object `ABC.NYC13.fdata` in the loop in class `nycflights13` is not empty?

Comment: I tried with a csv created by me for the above code with like 3 columns including origin and the code worked as expected. If possible can you share the complete csv.

Comment: @Klaus I uploaded the file to google drive https://drive.google.com/open?id=1W0UitxymL3SJ_kiXWrQrqoKoihSkuODW

Comment: @PiotrKorlaga I have tried the code and it was not empty. 
for(Flights ab: ABC.NYC13.fdata) {System.out.println(ab);} and it did print out the data.

Comment: Hi @Andreas, are you suggesting I should make my code more short and understandable? OR my code is entirely wrong?

Comment: @Klaus I created a more simple csv and run with the data. It did work as well. Not sure what went wrong with my original code.

Comment: Is the issue still exist or is it fixed and working?

Comment: @Klaus Still existing. It did work well with the csv I created with just a few data but when it comes to the original file, It did not work.

Comment: @boonboon93 I'm suggesting you **edit** the question and post code that actually **compiles**!

Comment: I have posted the answer

Comment: Don't use line-reading and `split(",")` to read CSV files. **Use a CSV parser!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I may have found the issue, Your original csv file contains formatting in cells. Clear the formatting for all cells except for the `time_hour` column.

Or as a quick fix, change your code in `nycflights13` class inside the loop

```
if( ab.getorigin().equals( "\"EWR\"" ) ) // nycflights13 class
```

As a side note and as mentioned in comments, next time use a CSV parser, this will avoid many complications when dealing with CSV files

Comment: Correct recommendation would be: Use a CSV parser to parse CSV files.

Comment: Yes, I provided the solution for the code and pointed out where the issue is, not a recommendation.

Comment: @Klaus Thanks a lot!, It solved the issue. And after i clear the format, my codes work as well. Will try to explore the CSV parser you mentioned. How do I read the operator/symbol for "\"EWR\"" ?